# Ambiguous overload for operator>>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std, cin

I'm starting learning C++ and I cant find the cause of the error below. This code is in the book "Teach Yourself C++ ".

main.cpp:13: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >> (int)ip’

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

enum ignition_parts {distributor=1,cap,points,plug,condenser,coil,wires,done};


 main() {

 ignition_parts ip;
 do{
 cout << "\nInsira no item (1-7, 8 para sair):";
 std::cin >> (int)ip;
 switch(ip){

     case distributor: cout<< "Distribuidor";
     break;

     case cap: cout<< "Tampa";
     break;

     case points: cout << "Pontos";
     break;

     case plug:cout << "Vela";
     break;

     case condenser: cout<<"Condensador";
     break;

     case done: break;

     default: cout << "No item ignorado";
     break;

     }

     } while (ip != done);

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be getting multiple matches, you should be getting no matches.

Comment: @chris it's getting lots of matches requiring /equally bad/ implicit conversions. Welcome to C++ hell :)

Comment: @sehe, Well, yes. What I meant to say was that the compiler must suck pretty badly if it's finding equally *good* matches so as to have the call be ambiguous.

Comment: @chris It would suck a lot harder if it wasn't conforming to the language specs...

Comment: @sehe, What part of the language says you can do `std::cin >> (int)ip;`? It's like `std::cin >> 2;` in a way.

Comment: @chris remember - `operator>>` is just a function! You can define `void operator>>(std::istream const&, int) {}` just fine... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa91c4349036af74

Comment: @sehe, Okay, I see what you're getting at, although `<iostream>` doesn't define anything like that and `std::cin` cannot implicitly convert to any appropriate arithmetic type for a bit shift.

Comment: Thanks !! Just a freshman mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion:  Use an array for identifier to string conversions.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ignition_parts ip)
{
    static const char * names[] =
    {
       "Nothing",
       "Distribuidor", "Tampa", "Pontos", "Vela", "Condensador"
    }
    // Test ip for validity first.
    os << names[ip];
}
```

The above is not safe because if the `enum` order changes, the mappings in the above table will produce incorrect results.  Also, if the `enum` is expanded and the array isn't, you can get a runtime buffer overrun error (nasty).

A safer method is to include the identifier in the table:

```
struct Entry
{
    ignition_parts part_id;
    const char *   name;
};
const Entry  name_table[] =
{
  {distributor, "Distribuidor"},
  {cap,         "Tampa"},
  {points,      "Pontos"},
  {plug,        "Vela"},
  {condenser,   "Condensador"},
};
const unsigned number_of_entries =
    sizeof(name_table) / sizeof(name_table[0]);
```

You search each entry for a matching ID, then return the `name` field of the table entry.

A good benefit of this method is that you can add entries without changing code and the order is not dependent (order of entries does not matter).

Answer (score 4):

All overloads are equally bad ;)

```
    std::cin >> (int&)ip;
```

Would be "close" Since you cannot assign to an rvalue.

However, do

```
    int tmp;
    std::cin >> tmp;
    ip = static_cast<ignition_parts>(tmp);
```

instead for portability/defined behaviour

Here's a version with added error-handling, and extracting the output streaming of `ip` into it's own function: **[See it Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)** on Coliru

```
#include<iostream>

enum ignition_parts {distributor=1,cap,points,plug,condenser,coil,wires,done};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ignition_parts ip)
{
    switch(ip) {
            case distributor: return os << "Distribuidor";
            case cap:         return os << "Tampa";
            case points:      return os << "Pontos";
            case plug:        return os << "Vela";
            case condenser:   return os << "Condensador";
            default:          return os << "No item ignorado";
    }
    // unreachable
}

int main() {
    ignition_parts ip;
    do {
        std::cout << "\nInsira no item (1-7, 8 para sair): ";

        int tmp;
        if(std::cin >> tmp) 
        {
            ip = static_cast<ignition_parts>(tmp);

            if (ip == done) {
                break;
            }

            std::cout << ip;
        } else {
            if(std::cin.eof()) {
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "Whoops: invalid input\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
        }

    } while(std::cin && ip != done);

}
```